# Prove that the range of $f$ does not contain $1$.

Tags: functions

Let $f(x) = (\ln ({7x−x^2\over12}))^{3\over2}$

Prove that the range of $f$ does not contain $1$.

My approach: $f$ is defined for $x(x-7)<0$. So, range of $f$ should be $(0,7)$. $\therefore$ It should contain $1$.

Comment: What you computed is the domain of the function and not the range. To find the range, suppose that $y$ is in the range and try to figure out what $x$ is in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$1 \in R(f)$ if and only if 
$$
  7x - x^2
= 12 e,
$$
or 
$$
  x
= \frac{7 \pm \sqrt{49-48 e}}{2}.
$$
Since you are dealing with a function with a real domain, and these values of $x$ do not lie in $\mathbb{R}$, there is no pre-image of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

(ln((7x-(x^2))/12))^(3/2)=1

or, (7x-(x^2))/12)=e (2

or, (x^2)-7x+12e=0

discriminant=49-48e (<0)
 no real roots of x could be found for f(x)=7.
 thus, by theory of contradiction, f(x) could never be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are confounding the domain of a function with its range. A domain is the set of valid inputs of a function. The range of a function is its set of possible outputs. In your case, that set of inputs requires two things: (i) that $\frac{7x−x^2}{12}$ is positive, and (ii) that $ln(\frac{7x−x^2}{12})$ is positive. These constraints can be simplified so that the only costraint is that $\frac{7x−x^2}{12} \geq 1$. Solving the resulting inequality ($x^2-7x+12 \leq 0$) gives bounds on $x$: $x \in [3,4]$.

What remains is to show that this set of inputs never outputs a value of one. The easiest way to do this is to consider the following: the values of the function at $x=3$ and $x=4$ are $0$. Furthermore, the function is continuous as differentiable over the range of interest. The derivative shows a local maximum at 3.5, and the value at this point (estimated as $0.0029608...$) is less than one, so the function's range does not include 1.